# Hierarchical POJOs not being properly serialized to JSON by RESTEasy/Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, resteasy

I have two POJOs defined as follows,

```
public class VertexDefinition {
    private final String name;
    private final Vertex vertex;

    public VertexDefinition(String name, Vertex vertex) {
        this.name = name;
        this.vertex = vertex;
    }

    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @JsonProperty("properties")
    public Iterable<PropertyDefinition> getProperties() {
        if(vertex == null) {
            return Collections.emptySet();
        }
        return Iterables.transform(vertex.getPropertyKeys(), new Function<String, PropertyDefinition>() {
            @Nullable @Override public PropertyDefinition apply(@Nullable String s)  {
                return new PropertyDefinition(vertex, s);
            }
        });
    }

    @JsonProperty("propertyKeys")
    public Iterable<String> getPropertyKeys() {
        if (vertex == null) {
            return Collections.emptySet();
        }
        return vertex.getPropertyKeys();
    }

}

public class PropertyDefinition {

    private final Vertex vertex;
    private final String propertyName;

    public PropertyDefinition(Vertex vertex, String propertyName) {
        this.vertex = vertex;
        this.propertyName = propertyName;
    }

    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String getName() {
        return propertyName;
    }

    @JsonProperty("type")
    public String getType() {
        final Object property = vertex.getProperty(propertyName);

        if (property != null) {
            return property.getClass().getTypeName();
        }

        return "(unknown)";
    }
}
```

My Rest method looks as follows,

```
public Iterable<VertexDefinition> getSchema() {
    .....
}
```

When I make a request I get a json response as follows,

```
 [
   {
       "name" : "Foo",
       "properties" : [],
       "propertyKeys" : [
          "a",
          "b",
          "c"
       ]
   },
   {
       "name" : "Bar",
       "properties" : [],
       "propertyKeys" : [
          "a",
          "b",
          "c"
       ]
   }
]
```

In short I get an empty array returned for properties while the propertyKeys is filled in.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think deserialization into an iterable works as you've tried. Could you try something like this instead in your `getProperties` method?

```
List<PropertyDefinition> propertyDefinitions = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(json, PropertyDefinition[].class))
```

Comment: I actually do know that this works but I'm curious why Iterable does not work for my custom type whereas it works fine for String.

Comment: I think you could return an iterable but currently you're not using any jackson mappers to deserialize your objects which is the main issue. Have a look at [this link](http://programmerbruce.blogspot.com.au/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html), I think it may have what you're looking for